# How Ruby string unpack works for extracting 16, 32 and 64 signed/unsigned values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby unpacking 8-bit signed/unsigned char is basically returns decimal value of each byte(char) as an array,

```
'12'.unpack 'C*'
# => [49, 50]
```

So, I can understand the unpacking of 8-bit signed/unsigned char from a string. But how the **16, 32 and 64 bit** signed/unsigned unpacking works?

```
'12'.unpack('S*')
# => [12849]
'1234'.unpack('L*')
# => [875770417]
'12345678'.unpack('Q*')
# => [4050765991979987505]
```

From the above output I can understand **S, L and Q** is picking **bytes 2, 4 and 8** accordingly, but how the value is calculated?

Comment: What do you mean, "how the value is calculated"?

Comment: Yes, basically I want to understand the unpack method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s basically the number in 256 base, converted to `Integer`.

```
▶ '12'.unpack('S*') == [50 * 256 + 49]
#⇒ true

▶ '1234'.bytes
#⇒ [49, 50, 51, 52]
▶ '1234'.unpack('L*') ==
▷    [52 * 256 * 256 * 256 + 51 * 256 * 256 + 50 * 256 + 49]
#⇒ true
```

Please note, `S`, `L` and `Q` are platform dependent. To ensure little-endian, one might use (credits to @NeilSlater):

```
▶ '12'.unpack('S<*') == [50 * 256 + 49]
#⇒ true
```

For big-endian one might use `>` modifier:

```
▶ '12'.unpack('S>*') == [49 * 256 + 50]
#⇒ true
```